# beforePageLoad failing when a view column is computed

Tags: xpages

I've got a view control which opens an xpage.  When the xpage opens, the beforePageLoad event fires.  It checks to see if there are any attachments in a particular field of the document being opened and if there are, it returns list of the filenames.  This was working fine.  Then, I was asked to change what's displayed in one of the columns of the view.  I added a variable to the view control's data section to access the row.  I then added some javascript to the column to display the data differently.  That worked and it displayed the data as wanted.  However, when I now click on the link to open the xpage, when the beforePageLoad event fires, the code that's there now fails.  It fails with this error at the starred line:

```
Script interpreter error, line=9, col=49: 'closureField' is null at
 [/Function_ReturnListOfClosureAttachmentNames.jss].ReturnListOfClosureAttachmentNames(CCEB1351591847CB85257E7C005EF68C)

function ReturnListOfClosureAttachmentNames(ltDoc ){
var closureAttachmentFileNames = "";
var thisLT = ltDoc;
var closureField:NotesRichTextItem = thisLT.getFirstItem("closeAttachments");
*>>> var eos:java.util.Vector = closureField.getEmbeddedObjects();<<<
var eosi:java.util.Iterator = eos.iterator();
while (eosi.hasNext()) {
    var eo:NotesEmbeddedObject = eosi.next();
    closureAttachmentFileNames = closureAttachmentFileNames +","+eo.getName();
}

return closureAttachmentFileNames;
```

}

I call this function from the beforePageLoad event and pass it currentDocument.getDocument().  I think I might have lost the document context after changing the column display data from 'view column' to 'computed value' but I'm not sure.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

thanks!

Clem

Comment: Clem, can you include your beforePageLoad SSJS up until the point you call the function. I bet you are right.  Also include view control's data section code.

Comment: Hi Steve... Well, it's just a one-liner: 

viewScope.closureAttachments = ReturnListOfClosureAttachmentNames( currentDocument.getDocument() );

Comment: The data section of the view control just points to a Notes view.  Nothing fancy.

The view column code is the following and works perfectly:


    var status = rec.getColumnValue("statusOfIssue");
if (status == "Pending Closure" || status == "Pending Closure Assignment" || status == "Closed"){
 return "LabWare Recommended";
}else{
  return status;

}

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Have you tried getting the current document in your SSJS function as opposed to passing it in?

Comment: That all is very strange. Here is another idea: Get the current document's UNID in beforePageLoad (works only for saved documents) and assign to a var.  Pass that var to the function as a parameter.  In the function, obtain the document using that UNID. I can't see how you can go wrong here.

Comment: Figured it out:  When I assigned a variable to the view, when you click on a linked column in that view, it loads the current ViewEntry into the context and not a current document.  So I put the unid of the doc from the selected ViewEntry in an application scope variable and returned it to the Document Id property when I open the xPage.  I have to now update all my views but there aren't too many luckily.  Thanks!

Clem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: When I assigned a variable to the view, when you click on a linked column in that view, it loads the current ViewEntry into the context and not a current document. So I put the unid of the doc from the selected ViewEntry in an application scope variable and returned it to the Document Id property when I open the xPage. I have to now update all my views but there aren't too many luckily. Thanks for working through this with me!

Clem –